# Difference between two bootstrap date with time picker

Tags: javascript, php

How to get the difference between two bootstrap date with time picker using PHP?

I used bootstrap date with time picker in my web application. I tried to get the difference between two dates. If I take the difference in hours it will print correctly but if I take difference in minutes its not printing correctly.

For example -  Assume that From date is 18-12-2015 04:00 and To date is 18-12-2015 04:15. In this case, I need to get the difference as "00.15". I also need to insert it into MySQL database and while inserting it needs to show "0.25" (Float (10,2)) format.

Comment: Elavorate better your question please

Comment: I used bootstrap date with time picker to my web application. I tried to get the difference between two dates. If i take the difference in hours it will print correctly. but if i take difference in minutes its not print correctly. For an Ex   Fromdate : 18-12-2015 04:00  Todate: 18-12-2015 04:15  means need to get the difference is  "00.15" .and also while insert into mysql database  it need to show "0.25" (Float (10,2)) format.

Comment: Added the clarification provided as comment into the question. Always use the [edit] link to add more information to the question.

Comment: Your column data type float?

Comment: yes .my column datatype is float devpro

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$diff = date_diff(datetime1,datetime2,absolute);
```

Here, 
*absolute is optional. Specifies a Boolean value. TRUE indicates that the interval/difference MUST be positive. Default is FALSE*

You can specify the format of the output as well:

```
echo $diff->format("%R%a days"); // will echo +7days
```

Comment: thanks for ur reply. Its not working for me. Pls give me a example